# Python Pandas replace numeric value to nearest non-numeric from above

Tags: python, pandas

I got a problem and appreciate if you could help to solve:

Suppose there's a column with multiples rows as below picture shows, I want to replace all the numeric values with the nearest non-numeric value from above, how to do with python and pandas? thanks a lot.

[click to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB6Xr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) for boolean mask, replace to `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then forward filling previous values:

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').notna()
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(mask).ffill()
print (df)
    col
0    AB
1    AB
2    AB
3    AB
4    AB
5    CD
6    CD
7    CD
8   EFG
9   EFG
10  EFG
11  EFG
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Comment: @ZeshenZhang - What is your column? Need replace `df['col']` to your column - if `A` then `df['A']`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.isdigit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) :

```
df['A'].where(~df['A'].str.isdigit()).ffill()
```

or:

```
df['A'].where(df['A'].str.isalpha()).ffill()
0      AB
1      AB
2      AB
3      AB
4      AB
5      CD
6      CD
7      CD
8     EFG
9     EFG
10    EFG
11    EFG
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ZeshenZhang Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.